# Updating to linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic occupies all disk space

Tags: kernel, update-manager, disk-usage

I just ran a normal update through the update manager that wanted to update me to `linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic`. The installation paused halfway with a message that the root was full. I checked the disk usage, and noticed that one of the newly installed files:

`/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/modules.ccwmap` took up 63GB(!). Compared to the previous version, `/lib/modules/3.2.0-24-generic/modules.ccwmap`, that took up only 4KB. It seems like something went awfully wrong!

As mentioned the update was paused when i ran out of disk space. There is no option in the update dialog to cancel or perform rollback on the update. Is it asking for trouble to kill the update manager?

Any ideas as to what went wrong, and what I can do to remedy it? It's only minimal how much space I can free on that partition (without deleting the above mentioned file).

If it is any help, the update was paused after this:

```
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-26-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

OK my system is back in a healthy state.

First: "Is it asking for trouble to kill the update manager". Yes, it definitely is!

I couldn't free any disk space manually, and I couldn't remove any packages while the update manager was in progress, so I decided to terminate update manager and reboot the system.

The system couldn't boot normally but in recovery mode I could open a root command line. From here I could see that the above mentioned file was now only 4KB. I have no idea what happened in between or why it became 63GB in the first place.

In Recovery mode only the Root prompt worked, any thing else was just hanging. To get the system up and running I did:

- In the GRUB menu edit the recovery mode to mount `/` as RW.
- Enter recovery mode.
- Go to the root command line.
- Fix packages using: `dpkg --configure -a`.

So the only question remaining is why `/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/modules.ccwmap` took up 63GB during installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today upgrading to 3.2.0-30-generic. My `/lib/modules/3.2.0-26-generic/modules.ccwmap` ended up being ~280 GB. I was able to `sudo rm -f` that file and then did `sudo killall update-manager` and was able to reboot without problem. After reboot I had to do a `sudo dpkg --configure -a` due to killing `update-manager` but it completed without filling up my hard drive. I have no idea what side effects might be left over but so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on friday after updating. This was definitely a problem in the update and must have been rectified after. My Ubuntu was so messed up that I couldn't even restart in Recovery Mode. I came across this article and this worked for me:

http://zeeis.me/ubuntu-error-gave-up-waiting-for-root-device/

It shows you how to use the Live CD to reload your partition where Ubuntu is installed so you can rebuild the messed up packages. Saved me from having a full reinstall and potentially losing data.

Hope it helps someone as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can solve this problem by free up disk space. You can use a tweak tool "ubuntu-tweaks",  to do that. It's easy. To download ubuntu-tweaks...type in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa  
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

After installing run it from system setting. Click on "Start Janitor". Then Select and clean. Do not delete old kernel. If you get enough space then update your system by typing

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If upgrade is successfull then you can clean old kernel.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, he *does* have the latest version of the kernel.

Comment: He have a problem with kernel its true but he also have problem with disk space. If he can clear his cache then it will make more free space to install latest kernel.